# Crashlytics (Fabric) separate organizations for application variants (build types, product flavors)

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, android-productflavors

*This is self-answered question to share my knowledge.*

I have a project with multiple product flavors and I want to integrate Fabric using separate organizations for each product flavor.

I tried to integrate Fabric using Android Studio Fabric Plugin. It adds

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="DEFAULT_ORGANIZATION_API_KEY" />
```

entry to `AndroidManifest.xml` of `main` source set.

I decided to rewrite this entry in application variant specific source sets:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="SECOND_ORGANIZATION_API_KEY"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then I discovered that Fabric Gradle plugin generates `crashlytics.properties` file with fabric api secret (AKA build secret) during build and I should include this file to source control. But this file is overwritten each time I build specific application variant because api secret is unique for each application.

How can I integrate Fabric using separate organizations for each application variant?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

During the build `fabricGenerateResources` task is called and it looks for a file named `fabric.properties` with following content:

```
apiSecret=YOUR_BUILD_SECRET
apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY
```

So all we need is to generate `fabric.properties` file before this.

I found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/alexsinger/2b5b1b7ae2d2fca1ffdb) and slightly modified it to fully support application variants not only build types.

Add this code to `android` section of `build.gradle`:

```
File crashlyticsProperties = new File("${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/fabric.properties")
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        def variantSuffix = variant.name.capitalize()
        def generatePropertiesTask = task("fabricGenerateProperties${variantSuffix}") << {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.put("apiKey", flavor.fabricApiKey)
            properties.put("apiSecret", flavor.fabricApiSecret)
            properties.store(new FileWriter(crashlyticsProperties), "")
        }

        def generateResourcesTask = project.tasks.getByName("fabricGenerateResources${variantSuffix}")
        generateResourcesTask.dependsOn generatePropertiesTask
        generateResourcesTask.doLast {
            println "Removing fabric.properties"
            crashlyticsProperties.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

It iterates over application variants and for each application variant creates task that generates `fabric.properties` file and task that deletes this file after Fabric Gradle plugin generates application resources.

All you need now is to define product flavor or build type specific `fabricApiKey` and `fabricApiSecret`:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        ext.fabricApiKey = "FLAVOR1_API_KEY"
        ext.fabricApiSecret = "FLAVOR1_API_SECRET"
    }
}
```

`ext` is an [ExtraPropertiesExtention](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) object provided by every [ExtensionAware](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html) object. It allows new properties to be added to existing object. In my case `flavor1` is `ExtensionAware` object and it can be extended with new properties by using `ext.someProperty = "value"` syntax and later these properties can be used as `flavor.someProperty, flavor.fabricApiKey`.

Also it's better to include `fabric.properties` to `.gitignore`.

And do not forget to remove `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` from debug build type if you used it to disable Crashlytics during debug. Instead of this you can disable it in `Application.onCreate`:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(
    new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build());
```

Comment: what is the ext object?

Comment: Does this method still work? I am using Crashlytics 2.5.7 and Fabric tools 1.21.7. I get the gradle error "Task with name 'fabricGenerateResourcesDebug' not found in project ':app'."

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I needed to remove `ext.enableCrashlytics = false` from the debug build type for that gradle task to be generated. Testing it out now.

I do have the question of how the apiKey in fabric.properties works. Does this replace the need for having it in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, you only need fabric.properties.

Comment: Inspecting the AndroidManifest.xml within the apk package, I see the apiKey is in fact added to the final manifest in the build. Good to know how this works! Thanks.

Comment: Gradle complains that there's no fabricGenerateResourcesDevelopmentDebug task.. what should I do?

Comment: @atlanteh Could you create separate question with your `build.gradle`?

Comment: actually I didn't notice @JeffLockhart already posted here in comments the solution

Comment: @atlanteh Added this to answer.

Comment: @mixel maybe it's worth noting that if one distribute applications via Fabric Beta, you also require to make the task `crashlyticsUploadDistribution*` dependent on `generatePropertiesTask*` too.

Answer (score 8):

If you're not opposed to using an application id suffix, you don't need separate organizations. The crashes and answers will be treated as separate apps.

For instance, let's say my application id is `io.example`

In your build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
  }
  release {
    //options
  }
}
```

After you deploy the debug version to a device or emulator, on the Fabric site you will see two apps:

- `io.example`
- `io.example.debug`

One thing that is nice about this approach is that you can also keep track of other build flavors seprately: `io.exmaple.free`, `io.exmaple.paid`, `io.example.exterprise`, and so on.

Comment: This is failing with error `No matching client found for package name com.xxx.xxx.debug`. This error is caused by `:app:processLiveGoogleServices`

Comment: @CerlinBoss That is a different error. You have not set up your Google APIs for this "new" app. .debug is a new app!

Comment: I think the question was about when you have to use different organizations (i.e. different API secret) for different flavors.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, which is also compatible with Gradle 5.x+ is to create separate `fabric.properties` files for each of the build variants that needs a unique Fabric API key and secret. Create the `fabric.properties` files as:

```
#Contains API Secret used to validate your application. Commit to internal source control; avoid making secret public.
apiSecret=YOUR_API_SECRET
apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY
```

replacing `YOUR_API_SECRET` with the build variant's API secret and `YOUR_API_KEY` with the build variant's API key.

Then place each variant's `fabric.properties` under the project `src/variant` folder, e.g. `app/src/debug` or `app/src/release`. [See documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) on build variants for additional details.

At build time, the `fabric.properties` for the variant being built will be used.