# Crashlytics distribution with multiple flavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

**I have multiple `flavors` and trying to distribute them separately using `Beta Distribution`:**

```
productFlavors {
    appOne{
        applicationId 'com.example.appOne'
        manifestPlaceholders = [ appName: "AppOne", fabricApiKey: "AppOne APi Key"]
    }
    appTwo{
        applicationId 'com.example.appTwo'
        manifestPlaceholders = [ appName: "AppTwo", fabricApiKey: "AppTwo APi Key"]
    }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="${fabricApiKey}" />
```

I have created two different organizations, built apps based on `flavor` and they are successfully added to the organizations. *However **distribution icon is being hidden in `appOne flavour` while working fine for `appTwo flavor` (as shown below):***

[image]

I have also tried the old way (generating `fabric.properties` while `build`) without any success: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700680/crashlytics-found-an-invalid-api-key/25704532#25704532) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462065/crashlytics-fabric-separate-organizations-for-application-variants-build-type).

***Is there a way that I can distribute multiple apps based on `flavor`?***

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. 

If you go to your Beta dashboard on Fabric for the second app, do you see any terms or conditions to accept?

Comment: Sorry, I meant for app one, the one without the beta icon.

Comment: @MikeBonnell - unrelated but fantastic to see you guys monitoring SO.

Comment: @MikeBonnell unfortunately not. There is nothing related with terms or conditions in both of the apps

Comment: Hmm, can you email into support(at)fabric(dot)io or share the first app id?

Comment: i used approach like you did. and working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what was the reason, however, contacting the **fabric support** team managed to solve it. It looked liked somehow the beta distribution was not being *enabled* without accepting some terms (which somehow was not being shown on my app).

Anyway, they provided me a `link` which redirected me to those terms. Accepting them enabled `Beta Distribution` for both of the apps.