# Automation for detecting crash Android

Tags: android

I have an application that has 77 product flavors. I have a crash that has been detected but I don't know on which flavor it could have been. How can I automate the process of detecting the crash on one of the station?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Crash Reporting
Crash Reporting creates detailed reports of the errors in your app. Errors are grouped into issues based on having similar stack traces, and triaged by the severity of impact on your users. In addition to automatic reports, you can log custom events to help capture the steps leading up to a crash.

To report server-side errors, we recommend using Google Stackdriver Error Reporting, which supports Node.js, Python, Go, Java, PHP, and Ruby errors.

Comment: integrate firebase into your application

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// The following code allows an app to report Crashlytics crashes separately 
// for release and debug buildTypes when using Gradle. This code should be inserted 
// into the specified locations within your build.gradle (Module:app) file

    // The buildTypes { } block should be inserted inside the android { } block
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.crashlyticsApiSecret = "release api secret"
            ext.crashlyticsApiKey = "release api key"
        }
        debug {
            ext.crashlyticsApiSecret = "debug api secret"
            ext.crashlyticsApiKey = "debug api key"
        }
    }

// The following code can be inserted at the bottom of your build.gradle file
import com.crashlytics.tools.utils.PropertiesUtils

File crashlyticsProperties = new File("${project.projectDir.absolutePath}/fabric.properties")
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantSuffix = variant.name.capitalize()
    def generateResourcesTask = project.tasks.getByName("fabricGenerateResources${variantSuffix}")
    def generatePropertiesTask = task("fabricGenerateProperties${variantSuffix}") << {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        println "...copying apiSecret for ${variant.name}"
        properties.put("apiSecret", variant.buildType.ext.crashlyticsApiSecret)
        println "...copying apiKey for ${variant.name}"
        properties.put("apiKey", variant.buildType.ext.crashlyticsApiKey)
        PropertiesUtils.injectPropertyInFile(crashlyticsProperties, properties, "")
    }
    generateResourcesTask.dependsOn generatePropertiesTask
}
```

For detail, please read [this GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/alexsinger/2b5b1b7ae2d2fca1ffdb) and [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462065/crashlytics-fabric-separate-organizations-for-application-variants-build-type).